# While reading .pkcs12 file content as method parameter getting error as java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=58, too big

Tags: java, pkcs#12

I am getting .pkcs12 file content as string param from other service. In java while reading getting error as

> java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=58, too
> big.

sample code:

```
private void getAccessToken(String pkcs12Content){
 InputStream appSecretStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs12Content.getBytes());  
ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication
              .builder(clientId, ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate(appSecretStream,
              secretPassword)) .authority(url).build();
}
```

I am using msal4j library to connect to the azure service.
The issue might be due to change in the format of content while taken to String. Let me know how to read content?
Note: The method call is done from JavaScript code.

Comment: Can you please share an [mcve]

Comment: Also, the complete stacktrace maybe helpful

Comment: The question is how does the other service convert the bytes of the .pkcs12 file into a string. Does it use base64 encoding? That would be the best case and you would need call methods from `java.util.Base64` to convert the string into a byte array. If it uses some (random) charset that would be bad, because for many charsets there is **no** lossless transformation from byte array to characters to byte array.